# How to configure server-side out-of-office replies in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon, out-of-office

Is it possible to set up server-side out-of-office replies directly from Thunderbird? What is the recommended solution?
I'd like to avoid having to resort to webmail.

Answer (score 1):

Most servers do not allow this – that is, not in a standard manner that Thunderbird could support.

The only exception is if the server uses Sieve for filtering *and* provides the ManageSieve protocol, for which Thunderbird has an addon.

Comment: Are you referring to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/sieve/ ?

Comment: Yes. But very few providers (even those using Sieve internally) will let you connect through that.

Comment: Well that's not a problem, I'm managing our own server :) Anyway, since this plugin handles generic sieve filters, I figure I'll prepare "out-of-office" templates on the server and then each user will enable/disable them from the plugin itself as required... Thanks!